# Extracting an element from a semi-colon separated varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where one column is a semi-colon separated set of values. I want to query for all rows that have one of my values in that column, and extract that value as part of the result set. Eg.

```
MyTable
[Name], [Tags]
Bob, A;B;C
Alice, Me-X
Janet, Me-Y;A
```

If the values I care about are in the set [Me-X, Me-Y, Me-Z] (this is a known set, but it's not stored anywhere), I want to select the name, and the value from the Tags column. So such a select would return:

```
Alice, Me-X
Janet, Me-Y
```

Curently, it's trivial to get the records and all the tags with something like this:

```
SELECT [Name], [Tags] FROM MyTable WHERE [Tags] LIKE '%Me-%'
```

... but splitthing the Tags column and pulling out the tag is something I'm not sure how to do. I have looked around and it [seems like](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) splitting a string in SQL is less than ideal. This is exacerbated by the fact that I can't make schema changes, or add SPROCS to the DB.

Does anyone know a better way for how I might be able to go about this under these constraints?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to select the tag that you are searching for try this (this isn't actually selecting the tag value from the table but the value is in there so that is beside the point

```
DECLARE @myTag nvarchar(10)
SET @myTag='Me'
SELECT [Name], @myTag [Tags] 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE [Tags] LIKE '%;'+@myTag+ ';%' --if your tag is in the middle of the string
OR [Tags] LIKE '%;'+@myTag --if it ends with your tag
OR [Tags] LIKE @myTag+ ';%' --it it starts with your tag
```

----Edit

Sorry I just read the question again and noticed that you want a set of values

Comment: I can guarantee that there will only ever be _one_ of my tags on a particular record, but it could be any of one of the dozens I have.

Comment: What is the approx size of this table you are querying in number of rows, 1000+, 100000+? and how often will you run this query will it be part of an application or run occasionally

Comment: ~300,000 and once or twice a day. It's a query in a data source on an excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of all tags, you can do:

```
select name, tag
from table t join
     tags
     on ';'+tags.tag+';' like '%;'+t.tags+';%' ;
```

Now that I've said that, it is a really, really, really bad idea to store lists of things in a string.  SQL has this great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a table.  In this case, you want a junction table, with one row per name and one row per tag.  I do understand that sometimes you cannot change data structures and are stuck, but if you can, introduce a junction/association table.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a list of all tags. It's a free text field that people can enter what they want into via the front end. users "tag" things with whatever they like for whatever reason they like. I'm inheriting both the responsibility of querying it and using that field in this way. I only know all of MY tags.